# Golang Calculator -- Can't divide by 0 error

Tags: go

I'm actually in a bit of a trouble...
I have a calculator, but when I want to divide nubers with them, I have a panic err saying that you can't divide by 0.
Well, I know that in maths we can't divide by 0, but I don't put 0 in my ints.
Any idea of the problem ?
Here is the code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func mult(nums ...int)  {
    result := 0
    total := 1
    for _, num := range nums {
        result = total * num
        total = result
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func add(nums ...int){
    result := 0
    total := 0
    for _, num := range nums {
        result = total + num
        total = result
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func sub(nums ...int){
    result := 0
    total := 0
    for _, num := range nums {
        result = num - total
        total = result
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func div(nums ...int){
    result := 1
    total := 1
    for _, num := range nums {
        result = num / total
        total = result
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func main() {
    var d [] int
    var args= os.Args[1:]
    nums := make([]int, len(args))
    for i := 0; i < len(args); i++ {
        nums[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(args[i]);
        strconv.Atoi(args[i])
        d = append(d, nums[i])
    }
    num := d
    if os.Args[1] == "*"{
        mult(num...)
    } else if os.Args[1] == "+"{
        add(num...)
    } else if os.Args[1] == "-"{
        sub(num...)
    } else if os.Args[1] == "/"{
        div(num...)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Well well well, you didn't entered a right operand ! Try with +, -, /, or * between double quotes")
    }
}
```

The command I want to run this go code is :

```
go run calc.exe / 3 2 [Infinite args,...]
```

Comment: Actually, here is the error code :
panic: runtime error: integer divide by zero
[signal 0x8 code=0x1 addr=0x4013c3 pc=0x4013c3]

Comment: If you don convert to float, `2/3=0`. And further division will panic.

Comment: `for _, num := range nums {
        result = num / total
        total = result
    }` this code eventually does the division by zero. Test it with `div(3,2,4)`

Comment: @YanisBendahmane The application ignores the error returned from strconv.Atoi. Print this error to find one issue with the program. This error explains why `go run calc.go * 2 3` prints `0`.

Comment: Note also that args = [ "/", "3", "2" ] in your example (your slicing of os.Args is incorrect).

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  The slicing of os.Args to args fails to account for the fact that the first param in os.Args is the command name as you say.  That means that, instead of a number, args ends up with the operator instead (where the rest of the code assumes a number, which is a problem).  So the first entry of nums is always zero (failed strconv.Atoi()).  (Doesn't help that both Args and args exist in the code--confusing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first parameter will always be a operator select, you can do something like that in your main func, you have a two problems in your main, you are ignoring the convertion error of a string to int and then this index of your array are setted with 0, and you are defining the array larger than you need because your first parameter it's not a number to your div func

```
nums := make([]int, len(args)-1)
for i := 0; i < len(args); i++ {
    ret, errAtoi := strconv.Atoi(args[i])
    if errAtoi != nil {
        fmt.Println(errAtoi.Error())
    } else {
        nums[i-1] = ret
        d = append(d, nums[i-1])
    }
}
```